# Knit PDF Output with CAT in R

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, cat

I am using CAT command in R to get following output.

The Output in knitted PDF file is different to what I get in console. How can I get similar output in PDF as I get in Console ?

In PDF Output, the print question and code output is getting intermingled.

```
header <- blue$italic

cat(header("\nAre there any Missing Values ? \n"))
anyNA(cars_df)

cat(header("\nHow many Missing Values are there ? \n"))
sum(is.na(cars_df))

cat(header("\nWhich Variables have got Missing Values ? \n"))
colSums(is.na(cars_df))
```

### R Studio Console Output

[image: R Studio Console Output]

### Knitted PDF Output

[image: Knitted PDF Output]

Comment: did you use `result = "asis"` in your R-chunk header?

Comment: Yes, I did. The output is same with our without results='asis'.

Comment: Any clues anyone ?

Comment: Please include full code chunks in your example with the header and all. A sample YAML header would be good too, as solutions may be different for HTML vs PDF output.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with html:

this>

[image]

results in this ugly mess >

[image]

Solution 1 is to use "hold" instead of "asis":=>
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to consider `echo=FALSE` …? Just in case you don't want to see the code at all.

Comment: yes, agree that is something to add if it is suitable. In this situation it was important to show the code.